# Selecting random values using Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, random, selenium-webdriver

I have a page that contains 10 drop down options and each drop down has a list of values. I would like for Selenium to run the script, select a random drop down and then a random value within that drop down. Does anyone have any insight on to how to get a random value selected?

Currently I have the code setup to select the first drop down that is available then select the first value within that list. The code looks like this:

```
// Selects the first drop down
selenium.click("css=div.dropdown"); 
// Selected the first value in the first drop down
selenium.click("css=td.dijitMenuItemLabel");
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4):

This is the code to select a random dropdown value

```
String []options = selenium.getSelectOptions("locator");
int index = (int)( Math.random() * options.length);
selenium.select("locator" , "index="+index);
```

Regarding dropdown, you can store their locators in an array and select the random value

Answer (score 1):

> try this

long number = (long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 900L) + 100L;

System.out.println(""+number);